# Get resource for reader from stepExecutionContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to implement partition step in my spring-batch application.
I've written a partitioner and try to use it in my step. My partitioner scanning file system directory and gets files to read, one file for every execution context. So I want to set this files from step execution context to resource property of my readers. 
I've found the solution for xml-based configuration. It is something like this:

`<bean id="itemWriter" 
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" 
      scope="step">
    <property name="resource" 
              value="file:#{stepExecutionContext[startId]}.csv" />
    ...
    </bean>`

But I'm using java based configuration. How can I implement this in java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late binding in java config is still available.  Below is an example of what you have in XML for java config:

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    protected FlatFileItemWriter value(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[startId]}") String startId) {
        ...
    }
```

That being said, with java config, you'll have to address loading the resource yourself.  With XML, we do the conversion of that string to a resource for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have already found the solution and implemented this exactly as you answered. It works, thank you again.